# Better way to understand Factor Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been struggling with understanding Factor (Quotient) Groups for the last few days.  I have reread my textbook, looked under this forum for ways to better understand and my instructor was able to somehow able to cover this important chapter in under 1 lecture.  I think it helps me a lot to really think of these things in an order of hierarchy or view them as an analogy to something that can be visualized (since I am more of an applied math person).  My struggle also lies in the fact that when I do a problem I just look into the book and I don't know the mechanics behind what I'm writing at all.  Can someone, who probably had the same struggle, help me with this?  I am confused silly.

Comment: Quotient groups or any quotient objects can be intuitively understood as a clever way of removing unwant information (though not obvious here in the case of groups). It does not hurt to read my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929631/dimension-of-quotient-space/929665#929665) about quotient space in linear algebra. For groups, the story is similar.

Comment: Some additional information. I think in the case of groups, the factor group (by a normal subgroup) is best understood with group actions. Go find a book Onishchik "Lie groups and lie algebras Vol.I", on page 138 there is something that may help you. Or I guess any other algebra book should mention it.